# How to add a "read more" link on User profile teaser display?

Tags: users, 8, navigation

I'm using Drupal 8 and I want to have a "Read More" Link on my User profile, that links from the Teaser display to the Full display. How can I do that?

Content types for nodes bring the "Links" field out of the box on the teaser display.

Comment: `links from the Teaser Display to the Full Display` of what?

Comment: @No Sssweat. I think this is about the link added to teasers in NodeViewBuilder.php

Comment: @4k4 I think so too, but I'd like to know what kind of view he has on the userprofile page. Is this a teaser of articles the user has authored? or he wants a readmore link of author's bio?

Comment: @No Sssweat: by clicking the read more link the user profile in full view mode should be displayed (e.g. full user bio and info)

Comment: I guess, you are looking for Jquery(expand) effect on the same page after clicking the read more, and do not want to redirected to other page, right?

Comment: @CodeNext no I just want a link from the user teaser page to the same user full page (with a regular redirect, just a plain link)

Comment: @scar, I have one more question, what is the user profile account visibility setting on your site in general. Are you want to show all visitors including anonymous? Or only user who are logged in can see other people's user profile?

Comment: @CodeNext Yes, everybody show see the user profile. I want to show for all visitors including anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

This you can do using Views and providing the code for Link on User page, follow following steps.

**1.** **Creating the Complete User profile at default Drupal account page:**

1.1 Add the all the fields on the Default user-profile what you want on fullDisplay(Admin/Configuration/Account setting/Manage field). So any user when creates a account, he will have all section to fill-out. For example My Full user-profile has the following fields.

- Name
- Picture
- Bio

**2.** **Create the teaserDisplay**

2.1 Hide the fields which you do not want on the teaserDisplay. So, on the User-profile setting page(Admin/Configuration/Account setting/Manage Display), now hide what you do not want to show on Teaser Display. Now for my setting I want to Hide Bio. So I will just hide this field at Manage Display.

So current user-profile field settings are:

- Name
- Picture
- Bio - *Hidden*

*Now, till this stage, we set our Drupal's default account page as teaserDisplay but simultaneously we created those fields which we want on fullDisplay, hence we kept hidden but we will display all those hidden fields using Views.*

**3.** **Create the Views-fullDisplay**

3.1 Create a new view page, Select USER under Views setting. Under pager, choose 1 item.
3.2 Now on the setting page, add all following setting as shown in teh following image. So here we are accessing that Bio field which we hide on User profile page.

> [image: Views UI]

- Contextual filter setting: Under contextual setting select `User: User ID` and under that select `Display all results for the specified field`.
- Path: Now as shown in the view set the path `/user/%/view-page`. I have kept last part here, `/view-page` as I was just trying previously, you can change to `full-profile`, but you have to change that at all places.

**4.** **Setting the Link on the teaserDisplay page (so we can re-directed to fullDisplay)**

To provide the link, the link should take the User-Id from the URL and can able to pass that User-Id in views URL, so Views contextual filter can provide the result of that User, from where we have redirected. Hence, to solve this I raise separate question and you can follow answer as shown below. I am not providing answer as you have to just copy from there.

[@ShawnConn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/45675/shawn-conn) has provided answer for how to add link on user-page. Full Credit goes to [@ShawnConn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/45675/shawn-conn) for this answer.

[How to get current path for user profile field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208944/how-to-get-current-path-for-user-profile-field)

**5.** **Output Image:**

**teaserDisplay- Default User Page**

> [image]

**Full Display - Views with bio field**

> [image]

*Now, this way you can add as many as field you want, just hide them so they does not display on teaser display and show in views so they display on fullDisplay page.*

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create your own custom teaser.

1. In Views, change FORMAT from Show: Teaser to Show Fields.

[image]

2. Add fields, title, use pic, user bio (for formatter you could use [Summary or trimmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8dyu.jpg)), and any other field you want.
3. Add **User ID** or **User Name** as a field. (depending on how your full profile view url is /fullprofile/[name]? or /fullprofile/[uid])

   - Then rewrite the output of this field `<a href="/fullprofile/{{ uid }}">Read more</a>` OR with `{{ name }}`

Your full profile page view url should be like this `fullprofile/%` with a contextual filter of User ID or User Name that picks up the second url as parameter.