# How to get current path for user profile field?

Tags: 8, navigation

On the user profile page, I want to add link field which will link to a view page.

For example,
if the current path is:

`sitename/user/1` *(profile page of user-1)*

The link should be:

`sitename/user/1/view-page`

It should take the `user-id` from the `current-path`. It should redirect to `sitename/user/1/view-page`, in general `sitename/user/%/view-page`, which is my contextual view path.

How can build this link field for the profile page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about this is a theme override of the user profile page:

- Copy over **core/modules/user/templates/user.html.twig** over to your theme's template directory.
- Have your theme implement [`template_preprocess_user()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user/8.2.x) in your MYTHEME.theme file to inject a custom URL variable.
- Modify your theme's **user.html.twig** to contain the HTML for the link.

For example, in your MYTHEME.theme:

```
use Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_user() for user.html.twig.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::request()->get(RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_NAME) == 'entity.user.canonical') {
    $variables['view_page_path'] = Url::fromUri('base:' . \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath())->toString() . '/view-page';
  }
}
```

In your **user.html.twig**:

```
{% if view_page_path %}
  <a href="{{ view_page_path }}">MY VIEW PAGE</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, Just one correction, I had to use `$variables['view_page_path'] = '/drupal8101' . \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath() . '/view-page';` "drupal8101" is my site name, so with previous one it was taking taking site-name. Other thing, the Link is appearing at `author-by` stamp also, in articles or teasers.

Comment: Yeah, appears **user.html.twig** is used in other locations where a user entity might be rendered. The code has been updated for route checking & Url generation.

Comment: This works perfectly, Thanks for your effort. Appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I want to use this answer to solve this [Question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207925/add-read-more-link-on-user-profile-teaser-display). I will provide full reference to this answer & you. Even that question I was trying to solve and this part I was  not able to figure out hence for that I thought to raise new question. Since this answer is provided by you so I am asking your permission for using this answer to solve that question.

Comment: Thanks for the courtesy, feel free to cite anything you want. It's not uncommon to cite other answers on here, just make sure to link back so readers can follow your thoughts.